# inodes continuously increasing on linux server with Nginx and node.js application

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a linux server on AWS EC2 running a node.js application (serving WebSockets and REST API requests) behind Nginx. The issue is that the system is continuously running out of inodes.

Because of that I have had to increase the EBS volume a couple of times in the pas, but I can't keep doing it since it's not the ideal solution.

On running this command (`sudo find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n;`) in each and every directory starting from the root, I found out that the `/var/lib/nginx/body` directory of nginx has the highest inodes consumption.

The above mentioned command outputs something like this:

```
      ...
      1 0065420628
      1 0065420629
      1 0065420630
      1 0065420631
      1 0065420632
      1 0065420633
      1 0065420634
      1 0065420635
      1 0065420636
      1 0065420637
      1 0065420638
      1 0065420639
      1 0065420640
      1 0065420641
      1 0065420642
      ...
```

How can I limit the creation of these files? Is there a configuration in nginx that controls that?

Also, is this a folder that can be safely deleted?

Comment: Are those filenames?

Comment: @SamMason Yes, those are file names

Comment: Might be due to request buffering, https://serverfault.com/q/511789/195166.  Your nginx logs would help confirm what's going on

Comment: @SamMason Thanks for pointing that out. I indeed had `client_body_in_file_only on;` in my nginx configuration that prevented the files from being cleared. I changed the config to `client_body_in_file_only clean;` and cleared some inodes manually. The inodes usage since then has been the same after I cleaned it up and is not increasing.

Comment: glad to have helped!  it might be worth turning that comment into an answer so people with similar issues get an obvious pointer in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `client_body_in_file_only on;` in one of my nginx configuration that prevented the files from being cleared. I changed the config to `client_body_in_file_only clean;` and cleared some inodes manually.

Here's a quick command to manually clear files older than a specific date:

```
$ cd /your/large/directory
$ find . -type f ! -newermt "2023-04-01" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The inodes usage has been the same since I cleaned it up and is not increasing anymore.

Thanks to @SamMason for pointing it out to this question (https://serverfault.com/q/511789/195166) in the comments

Comment: You can likely pass the `+` instead of `;` to `find` for a significant speedup.  It causes the program to be run with many files instead of one-at-a-time

Comment: Also, given these are files, I'd suggest not passing `-rf` as you probably want to know when it's not working